# PayPal link opening in Spanish in Iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, ipad, paypal

I am developing an application in iPhone in which I am using PayPal for buying physical goods.I have used `libPayPalEC` library and my PayPal flow is within my application.I am referring sample Pizza delivery App which is made available by PayPal for reference [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mobile-express-checkout-library).My problem is when I click on 'PAY with PayPal' the PayPal page opens in spanish language.Same is with the sample application.I want it to open in English. Please guide me regarding this.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the issue was from PayPal.Got corrected automatically